# Customizing JQuery autocomplete to add Static HTML content before and after the list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, customization, jquery-autocomplete

Hey i need to add HTML content before and after the list that is dynamically generated using the autocomplete........the following is my code snippet..i have tried append, prepend to `li` but no luck......and also i need to limit the number of items in the list to maximum 5. How do i do it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({

                   source: source,
                   select: function (event, ui) {

                       window.location.href = ui.item.value;
                       this.autohide();
                   }

               })
                 .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                     $("<li></li>")
                 .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                 .append("<a>" + "<img src='" + item.imgsrc + "' /><strong>" + item.label + "</strong></a>")
                 .appendTo(ul)                        
                 };


           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-add-some-items-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-matching-list-in-the-dropdown/) link. This will explain you how to add text at starting and ending of autocomplete's result list.

Take a look at the other AutoComplete related FAQs too in the list that might be of interest to you.